# Procedural Material Connecting

Tags: materials, procedural

I have small procedural circles on a sphere and I want them to connect from their center to the other ones centers in straight lines, Imagine a planet like Coruscant, is it possible to connect them?

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Example of Coruscant]

Comment: If you generate these circles procedurally, you should know where their centres are, thus it should be possible to to draw lines between the centres of neighbouring circles. It would be easier to help you with this if you showed your material setup. Please consider adding a screenshot, or uploading your .blend to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and [edit] your question to include the link to the file. It may also help if you provided an example image of what you're trying to achieve, rather than just referring to the name of a fictional planet.